# duplicate tag [if-else]

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, synonym-request

The tag [if-else](/questions/tagged/if-else) seems to be a duplicate of [if-else-statement](/questions/tagged/if-else-statement), and so is [if-then-else](/questions/tagged/if-then-else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I merged [if-else](/questions/tagged/if-else) and [if-then-else](/questions/tagged/if-then-else) into [if-statement](/questions/tagged/if-statement) and set up a synonym for it.

Answer (score 8):

They should all be synonymed to [if-statement](/questions/tagged/if-statement).

Comment: Note that in a handful of languages, `if` is an expression, not a statement.

Comment: Why not `[if-else]` as the master tag?

Comment: @Cody, Why not [if-elseif]?  I think all of those statements can be categorized as if-statements, they're all just variations of an if statement.  I think `if-statement` is the most basic term for that type of conditional.